# Problems with Git Push Heroku Master - No Longer Working

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

```
Ubuntu 20.04
Rails 6.1.4
ruby 2.6.7
heroku/7.59.4 linux-x64 node-v12.21.0
```

What I do / see:

```
...myapp$ git push   # this works fine
...myapp$ git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've searched and read through multiple threads on this, but nothing I've seen or tried helps.

I have been using `git push heroku master` for several years now.  Today it stopped working.  I last pushed to heroku 4-days ago. I do not see any output that helps me figure out what is causing this. I've not changed anything with my heroku client setup.

Yesterday I allowed some Ubuntu pushed updates to my system.  Not sure if that could have caused an issue, as I doubt they contained any heroku-cli changes.

I have MFA enabled. I've been using it for several months and it has not been a problem thus far.  `heroku login` in a terminal window works via a web-browser and a push to my phone.

My website is up and working.

I've tried `heroku add:keys`  did not help.

The logs do not show anything.

Ideas?  Help?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: "Connection timed out" is the networking equivalent to: "I dialed a phone number, I heard it ring for a couple of minutes, nobody answered, so I gave up."  There wasn't a recording saying "nobody here", there wasn't an error saying "the phone lines are down because of the war", there was just *no answer*. That's not a Git issue, but you might check to see if others can't reach heroku either, or if maybe there's something wrong with your network connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

`$ heroku git:remote -a <app-name>`
...obviously  is the actual name of my app.

I missed the announcement of this last year?  I'm surprised I was able to push to heroku as long as I did.

From Heroku help:

```
Could you please switch your heroku remote to the HTTPS URL?

As has been announced last year, the platform no longer accepts git pushes at an SSH remote. Could you please run commands like below to switch the heroku remote to the HTTPS URL?

$ heroku git:remote -a <app-name>

Regards,
Daigo
```

Then I should see:

```
$ git remote -v | grep heroku
heroku https://git.heroku.com/<app-name>.git (fetch)
heroku https://git.heroku.com/<app-name>.git (push)
```

again, `<app-name>` is the actual name of my app.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this post and your solution. We had a very similar issue pop up on Friday 3/18/22 at my org and your post really helped in solving the issue. For anyone else that encounters this, [here is the changelog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2215) regarding this issue from Heroku. We also encountered a followup issue and [found these steps](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1937) to be helpful. Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may also have to unset ssh connections on git global config in addition to checking the repo .git/config heroku uris are using https :

```
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku/.insteadof
git config --global --unset url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadof
```